# After an ajax insert, load list of all inserts without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form with several different tabs. The main tab has all main information about the person and the rest of the tabs are composed of several lists.

One of the tabs have a list of all comments related to that person. That tab also has a button that allows the user to insert a new comment.

What I do is make an ajax call and load the create view, replacing the list with the view. Something like this.

```
$("#btnNewAnnotation").click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Annotations/Create",
            cache: false,
            data: { personId: $("#personId").val(), withouLayout: true },
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("alert of success!!");
                $("#annotationContent").html(data);
            },
            error: function (statusText, errorText) {
                alert(errorText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Now the Controller what it does it dump a partial view allowing me to put the new HTML on the **annotationContent** div

```
 public ActionResult Create(string personId, string withouLayout)
    {
        ViewBag.AnnotationTypeId = new SelectList(db.annotationtypes, "AnnotationTypeId", "Name");
        annotations annotation = new annotations();
        annotation.PersonId = personid;

        return PartialView(annotation);
    }
```

this all works really nice and without any problem. The problem I'm having is after inserting the comment in the database. What I want to do is reload the list with all comments again, but only update the div **annotationContent**

I have the following ajax

```
$("#createAnnotationForm").on("submit", function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Annotations/Create",
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
               //This alert never gets Called!!
                alert("ajax insert success");
            },
            error: function (statusText, errorText) {
                alert('Error: ' + errorText)
            }
        });
    });
```

the reason I do this is because the are multiple forms on the view and I only want to submit this form. My controller has the following

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(annotations annotations)
{
    try
    {
        db.annotations.Add(annotations);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return PartialView(db.annotations);
 }
```

When I submit the form, I get the error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[RecruitmentWeb.Models.annotations]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RecruitmentWeb.Models.annotations'.
```

I understand why I get this error but I don't know how I can reload my List of comments without reloading the entire page. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to pass in a single instance of an annotation class.

I'm assuming annotations is a DbSet and annotation is your actual class.

So it would be

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(annotation annotation)
{
    try
    {
        db.annotations.Add(annotation);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return PartialView(db.annotations);
 }
```